# Deleting the first node from a linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list

```
void del (node* list) {
    int a;

    printf("Enter no. to be deleted");
    scanf("%d", &a);

    node* p;
    node* prev;

    p = list;

    while (p != NULL) {
        if (p -> n == a) {
            if (p == list) {
                list = p -> next;
                free (p);
                return;
            }
            else {
                prev -> next = p -> next;
                free (p);
                return;
            }
        }
        else {
            prev = p;
            p = p -> next;
        }
    }
}
```

This code deletes every node except from the first one.When I try deleting the first one, it give random numbers as the output.What could be the reason?

Comment: what do you mean by "it give random numbers as the output"

Comment: This: `void del (node* list) ` should be this: `void del (node** pplist)` or this: `node * del(node *list)` and implemented appropriately therein, for the very reasons you're having trouble with this question.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that your starting node is getting lost and you lose track of your linked list. You need to return your new starting node. `void del (node* list)` should be `node* del (node* list)`

If node being deleted is first node then return second nodes address, else return first nodes address.

This is how your list was (suppose)

```
 +----+-----+   +-----+-----+   +-----+------+
 |  A |     +-->|     |     +-->|     |      |
 +----+-----+   +-----+-----+   +-----+------+
 /
Head is pointing to location A.
```

Make `Head` point to second.

```
 +----+-----+    +-----+-----+   +-----+------+
 |  A |     +-X->|   B |     +-->|     |      |
 +----+-----+    +-----+-----+   +-----+------+
                 /
               Head is now pointing to location B.
```

Then Free `A` (represented by `X`), and return new `Head`.

Answer (score 1):

When you delete first node pointed by `list`, you are not changing it to new node. So your first node in list still points to old memory.

You need to pass address of first node and change that, something like:

```
void del (node** head) {
    int a;
    node* list = *head;

    printf("Enter no. to be deleted");
    scanf("%d", &a);

    node* p;
    node* prev;

    p = list;

    while (p != NULL) {
        if (p -> n == a) {
            if (p == list) {
                //list = p -> next;
                //changes where head points to
                *head = p->next
                free (p);
                return;
            }
     ....
}
```

you should call it as

```
int main() {
  ...
  node* head;

  del(&head);
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the signature of `void del (node* list)` because you have to returns the **new** beginning of the list when the head is removed.

I suggest `node * del (node* list)` add `return list` at the end of your code.

Answer (score 0):

`void del (node* list);`

`list` is a local variable. Any change you make to it will not be populated outside of the function. You need to pass a pointer to pointer to `node`:

`void del (node** list);`

or alternatively, return the new list start:

`node *del (node* list);`